# reverse every other line in a file, write to a new file in unix

Tags: python, perl, unix, awk, terminal

Say I have a file, `wassup.txt` The lines of which read:

```
wassup
donut
skateboard
? teeth. !
```

I'd like to reverse the characters of every other line, starting with the second line, and then save as a new file `pussaw.txt`, the lines of which would read:

```
wassup
tunod
skateboard
! .hteet ?
```

Ideally the solution would just use base terminal/Unix functions, or maybe awk, perl or python.

I know I can flip every line with the code:

```
rev wassup.txt > pussaw.txt
```

The question is how to only execute this on every other line, starting with the second line.

Comment: Are you allowed to use perl, awk, or python?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick all of those are fine.

Comment: @colin I added those tags that you said you are fine with.

Comment: Have you made any effort at all to do this yourself? I presume it's a homework assignment as it doesn't look like something that's at all useful commercially

Comment: @Borodin not a homework problem. It would actually solve a real bioinformatics problem I am having. I am an ecologist, self taught coding for working with very large DNA files. I have made an effort to do this myself. Also- you're kind of rude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Perl's options to assemble a oneliner.

```
perl -lpe '$_ = reverse $_ unless $.%2' file
```

`-l` (lowercase L) chops off the terminating newline and adds it back on when printing; `-p` causes Perl to loop over input lines and  print each after running the script on it; `$_` is  the current input line and `$.` is the line number.

Comment: One-liners are one of the things I miss about using Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an awk solution:

```
awk '
function reverse(s,    r) {
  for (i=length(s); i>0; i--)
    r=r substr (s, i, 1);
  return r
}
{ 
  print ((NR%2) ? $0: reverse($0))
}' file
```

The function `reverse()` reverses the given string and it's called with every other line.

Comment: Reason for downvote? Anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: beats me, nothing wrong with it, have an upvote to compensate.

Comment: Only issue I saw was that I thought the OP didn't ask for `awk`, but I was wrong.  Second upvote as a "so-there" bonus to the downvote. :-D

Comment: Agree with everyone. Nothing wrong with the solution though could be optimized. I have added an edit, if you feel it was too radical, please revert it. You'll have my upvote regardless :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

flip = False

for line in sys.stdin:
    if flip:
        print line.strip()
    else:
        print line.strip()[::-1]
    flip = not flip
```

Save that as, e.g. `flip_evens.py`, then fix the permissions (`chmod +x flip_evens.py`) and run it as `./flip_evens.py < input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

In almost pure bash, you can keep a variable to know if you are reading an even or odd line, applying then `rev` accordingly:

```
f=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    (( f%2 )) && rev <<< "$line" || echo "$line"
    (( f++ ))
done < file > new_file
```

#### Test

Printing to stdout:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do (( f%2 )) && rev <<< "$line" || echo "$line"; (( f++ )); done < a
wassup
tunod
skateboard
! .hteet ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution in Python:

```
>>> text = ['wassup', 'donut', 'skateboard', '? teeth. !']
>>> output = []
>>> for num, line in enumerate(text):
...   if num % 2:  # Starting with the second line (which is an index of `1`...)
...     output.append(''.join(reversed(line)))  # Reverse the string, then join it into a new string.
...   else:
...     output.append(line)
... 
>>> for line in output:
...   print(line)
... 
wassup
tunod
skateboard
! .hteet ?
>>>
```